# How to count frequency of numbers while accounting for the time of the data?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I am hoping to get some guidance as to how to tackle this problem. I have the following sample dataset with the dates in `YYYYMMDD` format:

```
data={{{20120802}, 193.9}, {{20120912}, 493.9}, {{20130412}, 33.9},{{20130502}, 193.9},
 {{20130802}, 193.9}, {{20130822}, 193.9}, {{20131002}, 193.9}, {{20131022}, 193.9}};
```

The "Y" values themselves don't matter for this question since I am looking at frequency. I am wondering how I would be able to calculate the frequency that such data points occur relative to the time period. I want to divide it so when I graph it in a line plot, it is divided into 4 quarters (3 months each) over the span of several years (in the example above it is 2 years) and for each quarter it includes all the points that occurred within that date range.

For visualization sake with the data above, the line plot that I want to make would have an x-axis with the tickers: `2012Q1, 2012Q2, 2012Q3, 2012Q4, 2013Q1, 2013Q2, 2013Q3, 2013Q4` and the data points would only be located on those tickers. So for points `{{20130412},33.9},{{20130502},193.9}`, this would be a "2" on the y-axis and have the x-coordinate of `2013Q2`.

If any has any pointers on how to tackle this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Show zero values and some other improvements

```
 data = 
   {{{20120802}, 193.9}, {{20120912}, 493.9}, {{20130412}, 33.9},
    {{20130502}, 193.9}, {{20130802}, 193.9}, {{20130822}, 193.9},
    {{20131002}, 193.9}, {{20131022}, 193.9}};
```

Convert dates

```
dat = MapAt[DateList@*ToString@*First, data, {All, 1}]
```

> {{{2012, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 193.9}, {{2012, 9, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 493.9}...}

All months with default value zero - must start with year or quarter

```
amo = Transpose[{#, Array[0 &, {Length@#}]}] &[DateRange[{2012}, {2014}, "Month"]]
```

> {{{2012, 1, 1}, 0}, {{2012, 2, 1}, 0} ... {{2014, 1, 1}, 0}}

```
DateListPlot[
 TimeSeriesAggregate[Join[dat, amo], {"Quarter", Left}, Count[#, _?Positive] &],
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Year", "/", "QuarterNameShort"},
 Filling -> Bottom,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 PlotRange -> {{{2012, 4, 1}, {2013, 12, 1}}, Automatic},
 Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

**Original answer**

To get an accurate aggregation we must start at `{20120101}`:

```
 data = {{{20120101}, Missing[]}, {{20120802}, 193.9}, {{20120912}, 
   493.9}, {{20130412}, 33.9}, {{20130502}, 193.9}, {{20130802}, 
   193.9}, {{20130822}, 193.9}, {{20131002}, 193.9}, {{20131022}, 193.9}};
```

Then we must transform the dates in a Mathematica-like form:

```
dates = 
  ToExpression[{StringTake[#, 4], StringTake[#, {5, 6}], 
      StringTake[#, -2]}] & /@ (ToString /@ Flatten@data[[All, 1]]);
```

Now we use `TimeseriesAggregate` to count the frequency per quarter

```
DateListPlot[
 TimeSeriesAggregate[Transpose[{dates, data[[All, 2]]}], "Quarter", Length],
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Year", "/", "QuarterNameShort"},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {{{2012, 8, 1}, {2013, 12, 31}}, Automatic},
 Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

And here are the monthly figures

```
DateListPlot[
 TimeSeriesAggregate[Transpose[{dates, data[[All, 2]]}], "Month", Length],
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Year", "/", "Month"},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotRange -> {{{2012, 8, 1}, {2013, 10, 31}}, Automatic},
 Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks eldo! Really helpful. Thanks for taking the time to write this out.

Comment: Hi eldo, just one last quick question. Do you have a recommendation of how to format the graph so when there isn't a data input for a period e,g, 2013Q2, it goes straight to 0 instead of connecting with the next non-zero datapoint? Thanks.

Comment: Please wait, will respond in some hours - and thanks for acceptance

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much eldo, I'd give you more upvotes if I could! :)